# Why is my regex not matching the string input?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following code below:

```
def convertint(prices):
    output_list = []
    
    for alist in prices:
        print (alist)
        price_int = re.match(r'([0-9]{2,3})', alist)
        print (price_int)
        
#         print (price_int.group())
#         output_list.append(price_int.group())
        
    return output_list
    ###

convertint(['$27' , '$149' , '$59' , '$60' , '$75'])
```

It's output is below:

```
$27
None
$149
None
$59
None
$60
None
$75
None
```

I want my regex match in my code to return 27, 149, 59, etc. without the $ but it's returning None when I try to match it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please note that `re.match()` only works at the beginning of strings. Use `re.search()` instead.

Comment: You just need `re.search`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the $ at the beginning of each item in prices

```
for alist in prices:
    print(alist)
    price_int = re.match(r'\$([0-9]{2,3})', alist)
    print(price_int.group(1))

$27
27
$149
149
$59
59
$60
60
$75
75
```

Comment: Note that this may give surprising behavior on input with more than three digits. I would recommend using `fullmatch` instead.